# Test a program in the same or a different programming language?

Tags: testing

1. When I started to learn about testing a program, all I learned is to
   use a library or package in the same language as the tested program.
   For example,

   - if a tested program is written in Python, its testing program is also written in Python and uses `UnitTest` class in the python
     standard library
   - if a tested program is written in C++, its testing program is also written in C++ and uses some test library in C++.
2. I just saw a project where the tested program is written in C++, and
   the testing program is written in Python. Instead of making the
   Python testing program to call the C++ tested source code, the
   Python testing program loads and executes the executable compiled
   from the C++ tested program.

General in software engineering, for a project, how is it decided to choose the same or a different programming language to test a program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you refer to unit tests, at least in the widest sense.

Normally you will use the same language for testing, just for the sake of simplicity. Using a different language just produces communication overhead between the tests and the tested code.

The only case where using a different language could make sense is when the language of your tested code is especially cumbersome (think Assembler or COBOL) or if you are not familiar with it. But the latter case actually does not count because unit tests and the tested code are normally implemented by the same developers.

Comment: Thanks. The project I referred to in part 2 is actually testing the executable compiled from the C++ program, not testing a C++ function in the program, i.e. not unit testing

Comment: @Tim: I see, in this case, it's quite common and convenient to use a scripting language (or glue language) like python to automate testing.

Comment: Thanks. What does "automate testing" automate?

Comment: Tim: It automates the process of providing inputs for the tested program and checking the results.